# Android: long click - как заставить работать так же как и onclick

Tags: события, android, view

Проблема такая: понаписывал я своих вьюшек (иконки разные с текстом) и для них определил onclick listener'ы, но тут проблема - если держать палец около секунды - то ничего происходить не будет (очевидно сработал он самый long click). Можно конечно создать onLongClickListener и вызывать в нём onClick, но тогда придётся каждой вьюшке назначить его. Пробовал поставить в xml longClickable = false, но это ничего не дало. В общем есть какое то нормальное решение, или придётся всё же обрабатывать onLongClick?

Comment: А по существу - пользователь привык к тому что клик - ожидаемое действие, долгий клик - либо альтернатива, либо ничего. Если требуется иное поведение - то нужно использовать onTouch, как посоветовал @metalurgus - но при этом распознавание жестов и их фильтрация ложится на Вас. И в помощь Вам дан класс [GestureDetector][1]


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html
но всё же будет проще вывести обработку события в отдельный метод, повесить оба листенера и вызывать метод из обоих

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как по мне - так если пользователь сделал LongClick, значит он и хотел сделать лонг клик...  
Ну а если уж сильно надо - устанавливайте не OnClick, а OnTouch.  
И производите действия, скажем, по отпусканию вьюшки

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {    
//что нужно сделать по клику и лонг клику    
}
```

Comment: А не произойдёт ли такой фигни, что пользователь нажмёт на одну view, перенесёт палец на другую и уже там отожмёт?

Comment: не помню, надо пробовать...

Comment: @imholynx обязательно произойдёт... и очень "обрадует" юзера))) ++

Comment: @imholynx благо это проблема легко решается проверкой координат касаний if(getX()<0 || getX>getWidth() return